# Why I didn't see Auto-Renewable Subscription in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, subscription, mobile-development

Why I didn't see Auto-Renewable Subscription in iTunes Connect -> In-App Purchases -> Select the In-App Purchase you want to create.

I see only Consumable, Non-Consumable, Non-Renewing Subscription
[image]

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I have found answer:

When you want to sell something, but you haven't sold anything before. 

You should open `iTunes Connect -> Agreements, Tax, and Banking`.

I think you have got `Master Agreements -> Contracts In Effect -> only row with Contract Type: Free Applications`

Apple doesn't give you access to functions for sell anything. Your App doesn't have access to products in `iTunes Connect -> Your App -> Features -> In-App Purchase`

**Decision:** 
You have to sign new contract in `iTunes Connect -> Agreements, Tax, and Banking -> Contract Type: Paid Applications` and fill fields [`Contact Info, Bank Info, Tax Info`]

Note: You should have 'Legal' role as a user. Then you will see "Request" button. If a role is only 'Admin' (without Legal rights), you may see only "View" button, and you won't be able to sign a new contract.

After that: you'll see `Auto-Renewable Subscription` in `Select the In-App Purchase` you want to create.
[image]

Comment: In TaxInfo only getting Australia, Brazil and US  Tax Forms, What to do with the indian Tax Form..?

Comment: In my case it was a privilege issue while updating info, done with super user.

Answer (score 14):

Note: If you don’t see an option for Auto-Renewable Subscription, you probably need to complete some contracts for your account.

Press Cancel and select My Apps from the top-left part of the screen. Then pick Agreements, Tax, and Banking from the options.

Make sure all the contracts are complete, especially the Paid Applications contract.

When you’re done, the status may show as “Processing”. Even so, you should be able to return to the In-App Purchases page and create a new Auto-Renewable Subscription.

Comment: Confirmed. In my case, I didn't have permission to see the outstanding contracts. Asked the admin on the account they were able to see and sign them. Option showed up after they did.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see the Auto-Renewable Subscription option, ensure your developer account has accepted all applicable contracts and have provided tax and banking information in the 'Agreements, Tax, and Banking' section of App Store Connect.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling with renew subscription on apple website. Here are few things to consider which can help -

1. Renew can be done only through account holder's account
2. I found the renew option only on Apple developer app. Login to apple developer app and check under account section
3. If you get error while clicking on renew button then check if icloud is logged in on the device with same apple id

Hopefully this will solve the problem for those who are not getting this option on apple developer website.

Answer (score 0):

There are options under the "Feature" Title.
In-App Purchase is one of the options and you can see only Consumable and Non-Consumable.
Below this option there is "Subscriptions" option. "Auto-Renewable Subscriptions" can be added under this option.

More info can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-subscriptions/set-availability-for-an-auto-renewable-subscription