# iOS App Store connect no option for auto-renew monthly subscriptions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, revenuecat

I have a new app I will be releasing to the app store that I want to be a monthly subscription with auto-renew but when trying to set this up in App Store connect, I do not see an option for auto-renewing subscriptions?? (See attached image)

This is my first *ever* app in my developer account that has NOT been submitted to the app-store yet so I'm wondering if this option is not available to me yet because of this or what?

I am taking a tutorial for RevenueCat where the instructor has the option to choose a auto-renewing monthly subscription when creating a new in app purchase.

My *only option as of now is to set-up a non-renewing subscription* and I'm not even able to modify the end-date. (See image)[image])

[image]

Comment: The start/end-dates for IAPs in App Store Connect are for the pricing of the IAP, nothing to do with the duration of the subscription itself, which is based on the date of purchase.  For non-renewing subscriptions your app is responsible for managing the duration and determining the end of the subscription period.  In general if there are issues with IAP creation you should double check that you have completed all of the legal, tax and banking forms.  In particular, ensure you have provided a bank account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this issue by requesting the Paid Application Contract as they state here: "To be able to create and edit In-App Purchases, you must be an Admin or Technical user for your iTunes Connect account. You must also have the latest version of the Paid Applications contract in effect and must have at least one paid app on iTunes Connect under My Apps."

check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42736959/16930239) for more details.